# Adding new tokens to BERT/RoBERTa while retaining tokenization of adjacent tokens

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, roberta-language-model

I'm trying to add some new tokens to BERT and RoBERTa tokenizers so that I can fine-tune the models on a new word. The idea is to fine-tune the models on a limited set of sentences with the new word, and then see what it predicts about the word in other, different contexts, to examine the state of the model's knowledge of certain properties of language.

In order to do this, I'd like to add the new tokens and essentially treat them like new ordinary words (that the model just hasn't happened to encounter yet). They should behave exactly like normal words once added, with the exception that their embedding matrices will be randomly initialized and then be learned during fine-tuning.

However, I'm running into some issues doing this. In particular, the tokens surrounding the newly added tokens do not behave as expected when initializing the tokenizer with `do_basic_tokenize=False` in the case of BERT (in the case of RoBERTa, changing this setting doesn't seem to affect the output in the examples here). The problem can be observed in the following example; in the case of BERT, the period following the newly added token is not tokenized as a subword (i.e., it is tokenized as `.` instead of as the expected `##.`), and in the case of RoBERTa, the word following the newly added subword is treated as though it does not have a preceding space (i.e., it is tokenized as `a` instead of as `Ġa`.

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer, RobertaTokenizer

new_word = 'mynewword'
bert = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', do_basic_tokenize = False)
bert.tokenize('mynewword') # does not exist yet
# ['my', '##ne', '##w', '##word']
bert.tokenize('testing.')
# ['testing', '##.']

bert.add_tokens(new_word)
bert.tokenize('mynewword') # now it does
# ['mynewword']
bert.tokenize('mynewword.')
# ['mynewword', '.']

roberta = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base', do_basic_tokenize = False)
roberta.tokenize('mynewword') # does not exist yet
# ['my', 'new', 'word']
roberta.tokenize('A testing a')
# ['A', 'Ġtesting', 'Ġa']

roberta.add_tokens(new_word)
roberta.tokenize('mynewword') # now it does
# ['mynewword']
roberta.tokenize('A mynewword a')
# ['A', 'mynewword', 'a']
```

Is there a way for me to add the new tokens while getting the behavior of the surrounding tokens to match what it would be if there were not an added token there? I feel like it's important because the model could end up learning that (for instance), the new token can occur before `.`, while most others can only occur before `##.` That seems like it would affect how it generalizes. In addition, I could turn on basic tokenization to solve the BERT problem here, but that wouldn't really reflect the full state of the model's knowledge, since it collapses the distinction between different tokens. And that doesn't help with the RoBERTa problem, which is still there regardless.

In addition, I'd ideally be able to add the RoBERTa token as `Ġmynewword`, but I'm assuming that as long as it never occurs as the first word in a sentence, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: I have the exact same question :)

Comment: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-properly-add-new-vocabulary-to-bpe-tokenizers-like-roberta/12635/3

Comment: Not directly helpful towards an answer, but still related: The reason why you're not seeing any difference in the Roberta tokenizer with `do_basic_tokenize=False` is the fact that it doesn't support this option to begin with.

Comment: Also, for clarification: Is there any particular reason that you are changing the default of `do_basic_tokenize` to begin with?

Comment: No idea—I'm joining a project that was already started. But since you've raised the point it makes sense to ask.

Answer (score 2):

After continuing to try and figure this out, I seem to have found something that *might* work. It's not necessarily generalizable, but one can load a tokenizer from a vocabulary file (+ a merges file for RoBERTa). If you manually edit those files to add the new tokens in the right way, everything seems to work as expected. Here's an example for BERT:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer

bert = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', do_basic_tokenize=False)
bert.tokenize('testing.') # ['testing', '##.']
bert.tokenize('mynewword') # ['my', '##ne', '##w', '##word']

bert_vocab = bert.get_vocab() # get the pretrained tokenizer's vocabulary
bert_vocab.update({'mynewword' : len(bert_vocab)}) # add the new word to the end

with open('vocab.tmp', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as tmp_vocab_file:
    tmp_vocab_file.write('\n'.join(bert_vocab))
    
new_bert = BertTokenizer(name_or_path = 'bert-base-uncased', vocab_file = 'vocab.tmp', do_basic_tokenize=False)
new_bert.max_model_length = 512 # for identity to this setting on the pretrained one

new_bert.tokenize('mynewword') # ['mynewword']
new_bert.tokenize('mynewword.') # ['mynewword', '##.']

import os
os.remove('vocab.tmp') # cleanup
```

RoBERTa is much harder since we also have to add the pairs to `merges.txt`. I have a way of doing this that works for the new tokens, but unfortunately it can affect tokenization of words that are subparts of the new tokens, so it's not perfect—if one is using this to add made up words (as in my use case), you can just choose strings that are unlikely to cause problems (unlike the example here of 'mynewword'), but in other cases it is likely to cause problems. (While it's not a perfect solution, hopefully it might get others to see a better one.)

```py
import re
import json
import requests
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer

roberta = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
roberta.tokenize('testing a') # ['testing', 'Ġa']
roberta.tokenize('mynewword') # ['my', 'new', 'word']

# update the vocabulary with the new token and the 'Ġ'' version
roberta_vocab = roberta.get_vocab()
roberta_vocab.update({'mynewword' : len(roberta_vocab)}) 
roberta_vocab.update({chr(288) + 'mynewword' : len(roberta_vocab)}) # chr(288) = 'Ġ'
with open('vocab.tmp', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as tmp_vocab_file:
    json.dump(roberta_vocab, tmp_vocab_file, ensure_ascii=False)

# get and modify the merges file so that the new token will always be tokenized as a single word
url = 'https://huggingface.co/roberta-base/resolve/main/merges.txt'
roberta_merges = requests.get(url).content.decode().split('\n')

# this is a helper function to loop through a list of new tokens and get the byte-pair encodings
# such that the new token will be treated as a single unit always
def get_roberta_merges_for_new_tokens(new_tokens):
    merges = [gen_roberta_pairs(new_token) for new_token in new_tokens]
    merges = [pair for token in merges for pair in token]
    return merges

def gen_roberta_pairs(new_token, highest = True):
    # highest is used to determine whether we are dealing with the Ġ version or not. 
    # we add those pairs at the end, which is only if highest = True
    
    # this is the hard part...
    chrs = [c for c in new_token] # list of characters in the new token, which we will recursively iterate through to find the BPEs
    
    # the simplest case: add one pair
    if len(chrs) == 2:
        if not highest: 
            return tuple([chrs[0], chrs[1]])
        else:
            return [' '.join([chrs[0], chrs[1]])]
    
    # add the tokenization of the first letter plus the other two letters as an already merged pair
    if len(chrs) == 3:
        if not highest:
            return tuple([chrs[0], ''.join(chrs[1:])])
        else:
            return gen_roberta_pairs(chrs[1:]) + [' '.join([chrs[0], ''.join(chrs[1:])])]
    
    if len(chrs) % 2 == 0:
        pairs = gen_roberta_pairs(''.join(chrs[:-2]), highest = False)
        pairs += gen_roberta_pairs(''.join(chrs[-2:]), highest = False)
        pairs += tuple([''.join(chrs[:-2]), ''.join(chrs[-2:])])
        if not highest:
            return pairs
    else:
        # for new tokens with odd numbers of characters, we need to add the final two tokens before the
        # third-to-last token
        pairs = gen_roberta_pairs(''.join(chrs[:-3]), highest = False)
        pairs += gen_roberta_pairs(''.join(chrs[-2:]), highest = False)
        pairs += gen_roberta_pairs(''.join(chrs[-3:]), highest = False)
        pairs += tuple([''.join(chrs[:-3]), ''.join(chrs[-3:])])
        if not highest:
            return pairs
    
    pairs = tuple(zip(pairs[::2], pairs[1::2]))
    pairs = [' '.join(pair) for pair in pairs]
    
    # pairs with the preceding special token
    g_pairs = []
    for pair in pairs:
        if re.search(r'^' + ''.join(pair.split(' ')), new_token):
            g_pairs.append(chr(288) + pair)
    
    pairs = g_pairs + pairs
    pairs = [chr(288) + ' ' + new_token[0]] + pairs
    
    pairs = list(dict.fromkeys(pairs)) # remove any duplicates
    
    return pairs

# first line of this file is a comment; add the new pairs after it
roberta_merges = roberta_merges[:1] + get_roberta_merges_for_new_tokens(['mynewword']) + roberta_merges[1:]
roberta_merges = list(dict.fromkeys(roberta_merges))
with open('merges.tmp', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as tmp_merges_file:
    tmp_merges_file.write('\n'.join(roberta_merges))

new_roberta = RobertaTokenizer(name_or_path='roberta-base', vocab_file='vocab.tmp', merges_file='merges.tmp')

# for some reason, we have to re-add the <mask> token to roberta if we are using it, since
# loading the tokenizer from a file will cause it to be tokenized as separate parts
# the weight matrix is identical, and once re-added, a fill-mask pipeline still identifies
# the mask token correctly (not shown here)
new_roberta.add_tokens(new_roberta.mask_token, special_tokens=True)
new_roberta.model_max_length = 512

new_roberta.tokenize('mynewword') # ['mynewword']
new_roberta.tokenize('mynewword a') # ['mynewword', 'Ġa']
new_roberta.tokenize(' mynewword') # ['Ġmynewword']

# however, this does not guarantee that tokenization of other words will not be affected
roberta.tokenize('mynew') # ['my', 'new']
new_roberta.tokenize('mynew') # ['myne', 'w']

import os
os.remove('vocab.tmp')
os.remove('merges.tmp') # cleanup
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add new tokens to fine-tune a Roberta-based model, consider training your tokenizer on your corpus. Take a look at the [HuggingFace How To Train](https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-train) for a complete roadmap of how to do that.

I did that myself to fine-tune the XLM-Roberta-base on my health-related corpus.

Here's the snippet:

```
from tokenizers import ByteLevelBPETokenizer
from glob import glob
import os

CORPUS_TRAIN    = 'corpus_train.shc'
TOKENIZER_DIR   = 'you_tokenizer_dir'

paths = list(
  glob(CORPUS_TRAIN)
)

# Initialize a tokenizer
tokenizer = ByteLevelBPETokenizer(lowercase=False)

# Customize training
tokenizer.train(files=paths, vocab_size=32000, min_frequency=3, special_tokens=[
    "<s>",
    "<pad>",
    "</s>",
    "<unk>",
    "<mask>",
])

# Save files to disk
os.makedirs(TOKENIZER_DIR, exist_ok=True)
tokenizer.save_model(TOKENIZER_DIR)
```

The 32k parameter was arbitrarily chosen. It took 10min on my corpus, then I was able to train my model.

Inside the TOKENIZER_DIR you will see the vocab.json and merges.txt.

If you are using a custom script for training, you can load the tokenizer like this: `tokenizer = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(TOKENIZER_DIR, max_len=512)`.

Comment: While this looks great, I don't think it works for our current use case, unfortunately. The design of our experiment currently requires us to ensure that the token(s) we're adding don't get broken up into subword tokens (but also that the spaces around them get treated as normal), and it doesn't seem like this will directly do that—though I'd be happy to be wrong about that!